# more /proc/mounts or ls /mnt/ or df hangs

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, fuse, toolchain

Hi I have done some toolchain upgrade, when I am trying to bootup the device it is not able to launch Webkit, because when directfb is probing the file systems for shared memory mount, it will look at the `/proc/mount` file, which looks like this:

```
# more /proc/mount 
tmpfs /var/run/dbus tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0  
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0  
shmfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0  
dsmccfs /mnt/dsmcc fuse.dsmccfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
```

I further checked and found in `/fusion/shm/shm.c` the function `fusion_find_tmpfs`. When the function tries to access `mount_fs` which is fusefilesystem, it hangs.

I removed the check for `access( mount_point, W_OK )` here the mount_point is /mnt/dsmcc and tried to boot up the device. My system will boot but in this case when I do `ls /mnt/` or `df` my system hangs.

When I explicitly launch that process from prompt I get below error:

```
# ./dsmcc_proc  
fuse: writing device: Invalid argument
```

I tried:

> ## strace ./dsmcc_proc Which breaks at rt_sigtimedwait.
>
> ## strace ls /mnt/dummy which breaks at stat64.

Can anybody suggest me is there any patch for fuse which I need to apply with kernel upgrade ?

Comment: What does `mount_point` in `access( mount_point, W_OK )` contain? Can you please `strace ./dsmcc_proc` and see what syscall with which parameters actually fails? Please update the question with that info.